# Trying to reject negative numbers and let person choose another but it finishes instead

Tags: c++

I am trying to make "Invalid number detected. Please enter a positive integer" appear when someone tries to input a negative number but, the compiler treats it like a zero which finishes the program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number, minimum, maximum;

    cout << " Enter any positive integers \n";
    cout << " Enter zero when you want to stop \n";
    cin >> number;

    while (number < 0) {

        cout << "Invalid number detected. Please enter a positive integer. \n";
        cin >> number;
    }
    minimum = number;
    maximum = number;

    while (number > 0) {
        cout << " Enter any positive integers \n";
        cout << " Enter zero when you want to stop \n";
        cin >> number;

        if (number > maximum)
            maximum = number;

        if ((number < minimum) && (number != 0))
            minimum = number;
    }
    cout << " your minumum number is " << minimum << endl;
    cout << " your maximum is " << maximum << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess you are new to c++..Let me give you some hint...why dont you think about using a single while loop with a (not equal to zero condition) and compute maximas after each input if necessary.

Comment: This is an ideal time to figure out how the debugger works.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help to start. If you need to stop when number is 0 then you need to check that, instead of checking `< 0` or `> 0`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number = -1;
    while(number != 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter any positive integers or enter 0 to stop: ";
        cin  >> number;
        if (number < 0)
            cout << "Invalid number detected, please insert positive number or 0 to stop: ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also, I suggest to pay attention on your coding style, you can start with [Google coding style](http://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html)